# Checking if at least one value in one array exists in another fails

Tags: javascript, arrays

The below should return true, but it is reporting false:

```
var array1 = ['fred'];
var array2 = ['sue', 'fred'];

var modified = [];

//create a new modified array that converts initials to names and vice versa 
    array1.forEach(function(element) {
            var index = array2.findIndex(el => el.startsWith(element[0]));
            if (index > -1) {
                modified.push(array2[index]);
                array2.splice(index, 1);
            } else {
                modified.push(element);
            }
    });

console.log(modified); // should be the same as array1
console.log(modified.some(v => array2.includes(v))); //false should be true
```

I'm trying to check if at least one value in modified exists in array2.

the opposite is also wrong:

```
console.log(array2.some(v => modified.includes(v))); //false should be true
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rL532z4c/)

Comment: Works fine for me. Maybe your browser doesn't support arrow functions?

Comment: @mwoelk see revised question with my full code + jsfiddle. using Chrome.

Comment: @p.s.w.g no, they're strings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in this line:

```
array2.splice(index, 1);
```

You're actually **removing** the found item from `array2` so of course if you look for that item to be in `array2` later it won't be found. Observe:

```js
var array1 = ['fred'];
var array2 = ['sue', 'fred'];
var modified = [];

//create a new modified array that converts initials to names and vice versa 
array1.forEach(function(element) {
  var index = array2.findIndex(el => el.startsWith(element[0]));
  if (index > -1) {
    modified.push(array2[index]);
    array2.splice(index, 1);
  } else {
    modified.push(element);
  }
});

console.log("modified: ", ...modified); // should be the same as array1
console.log("array2: ", ...array2);     // array2 has been modified
```

One quick solution is to clone array `array2` before you start modifying it, and then do your work on the clone instead:

```js
var array1 = ['fred'];
var array2 = ['sue', 'fred'];
var modified = [];
var filtered = [...array2];

//create a new modified array that converts initials to names and vice versa 
array1.forEach(function(element) {
  var index = filtered.findIndex(el => el.startsWith(element[0]));
  if (index > -1) {
    modified.push(array2[index]);
    filtered.splice(index, 1);
  } else {
    modified.push(element);
  }
});

console.log(modified.some(v => array2.includes(v))); // true
```

Comment: oh geez, I hate it when the problem laughs at you like this. thank you

Answer (score 0):

`array2.splice(index, 1);` modifies your `array2` so fred isn't contained anymore! Use `slice` instead of `splice`.

See also:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice

compared to:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice

Answer (score 0):

As the index will be determined as 1. `array2.splice(index, 1);` will delete the 'fred' from array2. and when you are:

console.log(modified.some(v => array2.includes(v)));

array2 is actually ['sue'] and modified is ['fred'].

Hence evaluating to false.

You should use `Array.prototype.slice()`
 instead of `Array.prototype.splice()` if you dont want to modify the array2